# How to change the global default Typescript Compiler (TSC) target

Tags: javascript, typescript, compiler-errors, target, tsc

When compiling this snippet of code, TSC keeps returning an error:

```
let message = 'abc';
message.endsWith('c');
```

Basically, the compiler can't find the `endsWith()` method for the type string. This same error is also returned by the [typescript parser that I've installed for atom](https://atom.io/packages/atom-typescript).
I understand that this happens because the compiler is targetting a version of Javascript which doesn't have that method for that type, which was introduced by ES6. Indeed, compiling with the command `tsc --target ES6 code.ts` doesn't return any error. However, I'd like to change the Javascript target version to a more recent one so that I don't have to specify the target version each time. [This can be done on a project scope by creating a tsconfig.json file](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html), but is there any way to change it globally for any future project so that I don't have to worry about it anymore?

EDIT: This is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020"
  }
}
```

If this is placed in the same directory as the project, invoking the `tsc` command while in that directory works perfectly. Also, Atom's parser stops signaling the error previously described.

However, I'd like for this setting to be valid for any typescript project I'd might start in the future. Since tsc looks for a tsconfig.json file starting from a given directory and then going up the hierarchy, putting this tsconfig.json file in the directory where all my project directories are placed should solve my problem. However, I instead get a bunch of angular-related errors.

```
PS C:\Users\gianm> cd ts-hello
PS C:\Users\gianm\ts-hello> tsc
../angular-node-express/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts:2:34 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'protractor' or its corresponding type declarations.

2 import { browser, logging } from 'protractor';
                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~

../angular-node-express/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts:4:1 - error TS2582: Cannot find name 'describe'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i @types/jest` or `npm i @types/mocha`.

4 describe('workspace-project App', () => {
  ~~~~~~~~

../angular-node-express/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts:7:3 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'beforeEach'.

7   beforeEach(() => {
    ~~~~~~~~~~

../angular-node-express/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts:11:3 - error TS2582: Cannot find name 'it'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i @types/jest` or `npm i @types/mocha`.

11   it('should display welcome message', () => {
     ~~

../angular-node-express/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts:13:5 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.

13     expect(page.getTitleText()).toEqual('angular-node-express app is running!');
       ~~~~~~

../angular-node-express/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts:16:3 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'afterEach'.

16   afterEach(async () => {
     ~~~~~~~~~

../angular-node-express/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts:19:5 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.

19     expect(logs).not.toContain(jasmine.objectContaining({
       ~~~~~~

../angular-node-express/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts:19:32 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'jasmine'.

19     expect(logs).not.toContain(jasmine.objectContaining({
                                  ~~~~~~~

../angular-node-express/e2e/src/app.po.ts:1:38 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'protractor' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import { browser, by, element } from 'protractor';
                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~

../angular-node-express/src/app/app-routing.module.ts:1:26 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../angular-node-express/src/app/app-routing.module.ts:2:38 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/router' or its corresponding type declarations.

2 import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../angular-node-express/src/app/app-routing.module.ts:10:14 - error TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option in your 'tsconfig' or 'jsconfig' to remove this warning.

10 export class AppRoutingModule { }
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../angular-node-express/src/app/app.component.spec.ts:1:32 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core/testing' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../angular-node-express/src/app/app.component.spec.ts:2:37 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/router/testing' or its corresponding type declarations.

2 import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../angular-node-express/src/app/app.component.spec.ts:5:1 - error TS2582: Cannot find name 'describe'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i @types/jest` or `npm i @types/mocha`.

5 describe('AppComponent', () => {
  ~~~~~~~~

../angular-node-express/src/app/app.component.spec.ts:6:3 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'beforeEach'.

6   beforeEach(async(() => {
    ~~~~~~~~~~

../angular-node-express/src/app/app.component.spec.ts:17:3 - error TS2582: Cannot find name 'it'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i @types/jest` or `npm i @types/mocha`.

17   it('should create the app', () => {
     ~~

../angular-node-express/src/app/app.component.spec.ts:20:5 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.

20     expect(app).toBeTruthy();
       ~~~~~~

../angular-node-express/src/app/app.component.spec.ts:23:3 - error TS2582: Cannot find name 'it'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i @types/jest` or `npm i @types/mocha`.

23   it(`should have as title 'angular-node-express'`, () => {
     ~~

../angular-node-express/src/app/app.component.spec.ts:26:5 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.

26     expect(app.title).toEqual('angular-node-express');
       ~~~~~~

../angular-node-express/src/app/app.component.spec.ts:29:3 - error TS2582: Cannot find name 'it'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i @types/jest` or `npm i @types/mocha`.

29   it('should render title', () => {
     ~~

../angular-node-express/src/app/app.component.spec.ts:33:5 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.

33     expect(compiled.querySelector('.content span').textContent).toContain('angular-node-express app is running!');
       ~~~~~~

../angular-node-express/src/app/app.component.ts:1:27 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../angular-node-express/src/app/app.component.ts:8:14 - error TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option in your 'tsconfig' or 'jsconfig' to remove this warning.

8 export class AppComponent {
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~

../angular-node-express/src/app/app.module.ts:1:31 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../angular-node-express/src/app/app.module.ts:2:26 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.

2 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../angular-node-express/src/app/app.module.ts:20:14 - error TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option in your 'tsconfig' or 'jsconfig' to remove this warning.

20 export class AppModule { }
                ~~~~~~~~~

../angular-node-express/src/app/input-user-data-form/input-user-data-form.component.spec.ts:1:50 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core/testing' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../angular-node-express/src/app/input-user-data-form/input-user-data-form.component.spec.ts:5:1 - error TS2582: Cannot find name 'describe'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i @types/jest` or `npm i @types/mocha`.

5 describe('InputUserDataFormComponent', () => {
  ~~~~~~~~

../angular-node-express/src/app/input-user-data-form/input-user-data-form.component.spec.ts:9:3 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'beforeEach'.

9   beforeEach(async(() => {
    ~~~~~~~~~~

../angular-node-express/src/app/input-user-data-form/input-user-data-form.component.spec.ts:16:3 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'beforeEach'.

16   beforeEach(() => {
     ~~~~~~~~~~

../angular-node-express/src/app/input-user-data-form/input-user-data-form.component.spec.ts:22:3 - error TS2582: Cannot find name 'it'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i @types/jest` or `npm i @types/mocha`.

22   it('should create', () => {
     ~~

../angular-node-express/src/app/input-user-data-form/input-user-data-form.component.spec.ts:23:5 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.

23     expect(component).toBeTruthy();
       ~~~~~~

../angular-node-express/src/app/input-user-data-form/input-user-data-form.component.ts:1:35 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../angular-node-express/src/app/input-user-data-form/input-user-data-form.component.ts:8:14 - error TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option in your 'tsconfig' or 'jsconfig' to remove this warning.

8 export class InputUserDataFormComponent implements OnInit {
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../angular-node-express/src/main.ts:1:32 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../angular-node-express/src/main.ts:2:40 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic' or its corresponding type declarations.

2 import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../angular-node-express/src/test.ts:4:28 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core/testing' or its corresponding type declarations.

4 import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../angular-node-express/src/test.ts:8:8 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing' or its corresponding type declarations.

8 } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../book-it/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts:2:34 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'protractor' or its corresponding type declarations.

2 import { browser, logging } from 'protractor';
                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~

../book-it/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts:4:1 - error TS2582: Cannot find name 'describe'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i @types/jest` or `npm i @types/mocha`.

4 describe('workspace-project App', () => {
  ~~~~~~~~

../book-it/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts:7:3 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'beforeEach'.

7   beforeEach(() => {
    ~~~~~~~~~~

../book-it/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts:11:3 - error TS2582: Cannot find name 'it'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i @types/jest` or `npm i @types/mocha`.

11   it('should display welcome message', () => {
     ~~

../book-it/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts:13:5 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.

13     expect(page.getTitleText()).toEqual('book-it app is running!');
       ~~~~~~

../book-it/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts:16:3 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'afterEach'.

16   afterEach(async () => {
     ~~~~~~~~~

../book-it/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts:19:5 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.

19     expect(logs).not.toContain(jasmine.objectContaining({
       ~~~~~~

../book-it/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts:19:32 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'jasmine'.

19     expect(logs).not.toContain(jasmine.objectContaining({
                                  ~~~~~~~

../book-it/e2e/src/app.po.ts:1:38 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'protractor' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import { browser, by, element } from 'protractor';
                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~

../book-it/src/app/app.component.spec.ts:1:32 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core/testing' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../book-it/src/app/app.component.spec.ts:4:1 - error TS2582: Cannot find name 'describe'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i @types/jest` or `npm i @types/mocha`.

4 describe('AppComponent', () => {
  ~~~~~~~~

../book-it/src/app/app.component.spec.ts:5:3 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'beforeEach'.

5   beforeEach(async(() => {
    ~~~~~~~~~~

../book-it/src/app/app.component.spec.ts:13:3 - error TS2582: Cannot find name 'it'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i @types/jest` or `npm i @types/mocha`.

13   it('should create the app', () => {
     ~~

../book-it/src/app/app.component.spec.ts:16:5 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.

16     expect(app).toBeTruthy();
       ~~~~~~

../book-it/src/app/app.component.spec.ts:19:3 - error TS2582: Cannot find name 'it'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i @types/jest` or `npm i @types/mocha`.

19   it(`should have as title 'book-it'`, () => {
     ~~

../book-it/src/app/app.component.spec.ts:22:5 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.

22     expect(app.title).toEqual('book-it');
       ~~~~~~

../book-it/src/app/app.component.spec.ts:25:3 - error TS2582: Cannot find name 'it'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i @types/jest` or `npm i @types/mocha`.

25   it('should render title', () => {
     ~~

../book-it/src/app/app.component.spec.ts:29:5 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.

29     expect(compiled.querySelector('.content span').textContent).toContain('book-it app is running!');
       ~~~~~~

../book-it/src/app/app.component.ts:1:27 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../book-it/src/app/app.component.ts:8:14 - error TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option in your 'tsconfig' or 'jsconfig' to remove this warning.

8 export class AppComponent {
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~

../book-it/src/app/app.module.ts:1:31 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../book-it/src/app/app.module.ts:2:26 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.

2 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../book-it/src/app/app.module.ts:16:14 - error TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option in your 'tsconfig' or 'jsconfig' to remove this warning.

16 export class AppModule { }
                ~~~~~~~~~

../book-it/src/main.ts:1:32 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../book-it/src/main.ts:2:40 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic' or its corresponding type declarations.

2 import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../book-it/src/test.ts:4:28 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core/testing' or its corresponding type declarations.

4 import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../book-it/src/test.ts:8:8 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing' or its corresponding type declarations.

8 } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 66 errors.
```

Comment: See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#using-tsconfigjson - you can put a file somewhere up the parent directory chain (e.g. in your home directory if your project directories are children of that).

Comment: Since my project directory is C:\Users\gianm\ts-hello, I've created a tsconfig.json file that looks like this https://i.imgur.com/S5a8Amp.png in C:\Users\gianm, but it doesn't seem to work. What did I get wrong?

Comment: Apparently the tsconfig.json file gets ignored if a file is specified when invoking the tsc command. Moving to the project directory and then just using the command "tsc", without any parameters, after setting up the tsconfig.json file in the same directory as shown in that screenshot in my previous answer, returns no error. However, if I move that same tscongif.json file in the parent directory, a lot of errors show up when calling the tsc command: https://i.imgur.com/A3z3mbl.png

Comment: Yes, that's what it says, the search is only if there are no inputs files. If you're still having a problem [edit] to give a [mre].